# iterate through columns in 2 different excel sheets

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel file with 2 tab sheets(A and B).
Each tab sheets has 10 columns corresponding to 10 different parameters.
I need iterate through both tab sheets and multiply column 1 in tab sheet A with column 1 in tab sheet B, multiply column 2 in tab sheet A to column 2 in tab sheet b, etc..
therefore I will obtain 10 columns corresponding to the 10 operations.
How to I write that in Pandas?
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: `dfs = pd.read_excel('filename.xlsx', sheets=None); dfs['sheetA'] * dfs['sheetB']`... I think.

Comment: What have you tried? have you read it in as a dataframe ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the comments had it pretty close.

```
dfs = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', sheet_name = None, header=None)
```

dfs is now an ordered dictionary that looks like this:

```
OrderedDict([('a',    0  1  2
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6), ('b',     0   1   2
0   7   8   9
1  10  11  12)])
```

You can get the multiplication like the comment suggests.

```
dfs['a'] * dfs['b']
```

Output:

```
    0   1   2
0   7  16  27
1  40  55  72
```

Comment: ok that's great thank you. What if I need to select only the data from line 10 of tabsheets 'a' and leave tabsheet 'b' as it is.
I have tried : dfs['a'][10:,:] * dfs['b'] but I get an error

Comment: dfNew = dfs['a']*dfs['b'] then just do your dfNew = dfNew.iloc[10:,:].